# What is the difference between segment.io vs Google Tag Manger?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have been using Google Tag Manager extensively and have even manipulated data layer to achieve the results we want.

Recently I have heard some people considering segment.io instead of GTM. Just wanted to understand what are the benefits of both and if one is better.